# pandas - create repeated data from change-indications in time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a time series that indicates location *changes*, like this:

```
08-09-2018 17:00:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 18:30:00, user_2, home
08-09-2018 18:40:00, user_1, recreation center
```

I need create "buckets" (in this example, maybe every 15m), and I need to fill every bucket with what was in the last bucket, like this:

```
08-09-2018 17:00:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 17:15:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 17:30:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 17:45:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 18:00:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 18:15:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 18:30:00, user_1, home
08-09-2018 18:30:00, user_2, home
08-09-2018 18:45:00, user_1, recreation center
08-09-2018 18:45:00, user_2, home
08-09-2018 19:00:00, user_1, recreation center
08-09-2018 19:00:00, user_2, home
```

*from there I will get dummy data for the location names* .. but that part I know how to do :) If it helps, feel free to group it like this:

```
 pd.crosstab([locationDf.date, locationDf.user], locationDf.location)
```

how can I do the first part?

I can do it like this:

for user, user_loc_dc in locDf.groupby('user'):
    user_loc_dc.resample('15T').agg('max').ffill() # just append these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.resample()` and `ffill()`:

```
dates = [pd.Timestamp('08-09-2018 17:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('08-09-2018 18:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('08-09-2018 18:40:00'), pd.Timestamp('08-09-2018 19:00:00')]

data = [['user_1', 'home'], ['user_2', 'home'], ['user_1', 'recreation center'], ['user_2', 'home']]

resampled = pd.Series(data, dates).resample('15T').ffill()
```

Yields:

```
2018-08-09 17:00:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 17:15:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 17:30:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 17:45:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 18:00:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 18:15:00                 [user_1, home]
2018-08-09 18:30:00                 [user_2, home]
2018-08-09 18:45:00    [user_1, recreation center]
2018-08-09 19:00:00                 [user_2, home]
Freq: 15T, dtype: object
```

Comment: this is very close. but it does not fill the gaps. at 18:30, user_1 should be home. at 18:45, user_2 should be home... Im not clear why that is true, since the early section does fill correctly. --  I guess what I can do is first split the data by user  with this method? how do I do that?

Comment: I got it the rest of the way, thanks to you.. adding my slight variation to question for others